# Problema con macro en outlook(vba) No se ejecuta

Tags: vba, macros, email

Buen dia estoy haciendo una vba para outlook me encontre el sig codigo y funciono,empeze a agregarle funciones
que necesito y todo iba bien pero no se que le movi que ahora ya el programa(o macro) ya no me lo reconoce el outlook
ya intente con reiniciar todo(outlook y windows) borre el proyecto y lo volvi a crear pero no puedo ejecutar mi macro
En la 2 imagen me aparecia el nombre de la macro y le daba ejecutar y todo funcionaba bien
alguna idea?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero supongo que te refieres a que ya no tienes acceso a tu macro. Dices que cambiaste algo, pero no sabes qué.

Voy a jugármela y diré que cambiaste el nivel de Acceso. Viendo tu código, veo que tu macro empieza como `Private Sub`, lo que hace que solamente se pueda acceder a nivel del propio objeto en el que está. Prueba a declarar todas tus funciones y procedimientos como `Public` en vez de `Private` a ver si así se soluciona tu problema.

Para más información sobre niveles de acceso y ámbitos, te dejo un enlace:

> **[Comprensión de ámbito y visibilidad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/understanding-scope-and-visibility)**